# How to create many to many relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I believe the title is self-explanatory. How do you create the table structure in MySQL to make a many-to-many relationship.

My tables are:

```
pr_resignations_request(
    id, userids ,managerid  ,resignations_date  ,reason_type    requested_date, last_status,    date_last_status,   agreed_date exit_details,   exit_checklist, exit_type,  comments,   discussion, withdrawn,  manager_comments
);

pr_exit_checklist(
    checklist_id, category, action item, responsibility, time_completion, status
);
```

I am trying to link the two tables such that foreach resignation request there are multiple checklist items. Also the checklist items can grow and shrink when added and deleted and also resignation request table can grow and shrink when added and deleted. FYI I am using codeigniter framework, I have No clue how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Pivot table with foreign key's of both the related Tables.

Let's say you have a Product table with columns `id` and `name`.
Also a Cart Table having columns `id` and `name`.

To create a many to many relationship between product and cart table, create a intermediate table with columns `product_id`(foreign key referring to `id` column of `Product` table) and `cart_id`(foreign key referring to `id` column of `Cart` table)

### Update 1:

In your case, the intermediate table would contain `pr_resignations_request_id` (foreign key referring to `id` column of `pr_resignations_request` table) and `pr_exit_checklist_id` (foreign key referring to `checklist_id` column of `pr_exit_checklist` table)

### Update 2:

```
CREATE TABLE checklist_resignation (
pr_resignations_request_id <data_type>,
pr_exit_checklist_id <data_type>,
Constraint FOREIGN KEY (pr_resignations_request_id) REFERENCES pr_resignations_request(id),
Constraint FOREIGN KEY (pr_exit_checklist_id) REFERENCES pr_exit_checklist(checklist_id)
);
```

Please replace the `<data_type>` in above sql statements to the data type of the columns they are referring to respectively.

Comment: can i have an example in my case? I am getting confused on how update will work in this case

Comment: updated the answer. The intermediate table can have any name you want

Comment: did you get that ?

Comment: should I add sql statements to create the table ?

Comment: its better.. i think

Comment: added... just replace `<data_type>`

Comment: thanks for your help. I will implement this in one or two hours time and will update you on the same.. thanks for now:)

Comment: CREATE TABLE checklist_resignation (
pr_resignations_request_id int,
pr_exit_checklist_id int,
Constraint FOREIGN KEY (pr_resignations_request_id) REFERENCES pr_resignations_request(id),
Constraint FOREIGN KEY (pr_exit_checklist_id) REFERENCES pr_exit_checklists(checklist_id)
);

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120343/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-shank).

Comment: Changed Table to Innodb engine and it worked thanks a ton !